# Oculus Quest testing on MacBook M1. Console debug messages not showing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity. I am able to build and run to the quest just fine. However I never see debug messages in the console window. Is this normal? Is the only way to see debug messages to use the PLAY button with the link cable on PC?

Are there solutions so I can see debug messages in the console, or to be able to use the PLAY button on MacOS? I have the new M1. Unity runs great, no issues, just can't see dang debug messages in the console!

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Console logging apps running in Unity logs. If you want to look at your logs from an android device, you should use logcat. You can get it as another unity window from Package Manager. Also, there is a logcat within Android Studio.